# Rust runtime mutable reference rules with RefCell

Tags: rust

#### THE QUESTION

When are `RefCell` counted down?

#### THE CASE

```rust
// Working
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let username = RefCell::new("");
    *username.borrow_mut() = "Genese";
    *username.borrow_mut() = "Salathiel";
    println!("{}", username.borrow()); // Salatthiel
}
```

Then...

```rust
// !working
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let username = RefCell::new("");
    let mut username_mutable_borrow = username.borrow_mut();
    *username_mutable_borrow = "Genese";
    let mut username_mutable_borrow = username.borrow_mut();
    *username_mutable_borrow = "Salathiel";
    println!("{}", username.borrow());
}

// thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src/main.rs:7:48
```

I did other experiments with `std::ops::Deref` without much success or insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`RefCell::borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) returns a [`RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html). If this `RefMut` is stored in a variable, [it lives til the end of the containing scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/destructors.html#scopes-of-local-variables). This is the reason for the panic in your second example - both `username_mutable_borrow`s live until the end of the scope, so they're colliding.

However, in the first example, you don't store the `RefMut`s in variables. They are *temporaries*. [The scope of temporaries is the smallest scope of the following](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes):

- The entire function body.
- A statement.
- The body of a [`if`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/if-expr.html#if-expressions), [`while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#predicate-loops) or [`loop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#infinite-loops) expression.
- The `else` block of an `if` expression.
- The condition expression of an `if` or `while` expression, or a `match` guard.
- The expression for a match arm.
- The second operand of a [lazy boolean expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#lazy-boolean-operators).

The smallest applicable scope here is the containing statement, and so they live only until the end of it. Therefore they do not collide.

Comment: This is eloquent! Thank you, Sir.